# Jquery plugin click events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been learning and trying to create my own jQuery plugin by following examples and tutorials online.

I have a plugin started that is called on each table row but my click event runs for each `<tr>` in the table.

How can i get it so my plugin's click events only happen for the `<tr>` that is clicked?

The plan is once I have it working properly to update some divs with some content related to the `<tr>` and the button actions need to do something with the data also such as remove the parent `<tr>`

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $.quote = function(el, options) {
        var base = this;

        base.options = {};

        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        base.$el.data('quote', base);

        function debug(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

        base.init = function() {
            base.options = $.extend({}, $.quote.defaultOptions, options);
            //var quotes = '';
        };

        base.convert = function(e) {
            debug(e);
        };

        base.ditch = function(e) {
            debug(e);
        };
        base.updateForm = function(e) {
            base.options.buttonPress.call( this );
        }

        base.init();
    };

    $.quote.defaultOptions = {
        buttonPress: function() {
            alert('hello');
        }
    };

    $.fn.quote = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var qt = new $.quote(this, options);

            $('button[name="convert"]').click(function(e) {
                qt.convert(e);
            });
            $('button[name="ditch"]').click(function(e) {
                qt.ditch(e);
            });
            $('.widget td:not(.td-actions)').click(function(e) {
                qt.updateForm(e);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
     $('tr').quote();
});
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="td-actions"><button name="convert" class="btn btn-small btn-success"><i class=" fa fa-check"> </i></button><button name="ditch" lass="btn btn-danger btn-small"><i class=" fa fa-remove"> </i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You should include a sample HTML set and example of use against that HTML for your plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other things not optimal but to address your specific question: Your code loops through all the TR, then adds a NEW event handler for every button - one event handler (new) for every row - SO with 3 rows you loop through those three, then add a new click handler for every OTHER row's button as well- all three of which get handled for every click.  Focus the addition of the event handlers to "this" TR:

```
    $(this).find('button[name="convert"]').click(function (e) {
        console.log('convertcall');
        qt.convert(e);
    });
    $(this).find('button[name="ditch"]').click(function (e) {
        console.log('ditchcall');
        qt.ditch(e);
    });
    $(this).find('.widget td:not(.td-actions)').click(function (e) {
        console.log('updateformcall');
        qt.updateForm(e);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please let me know about the other things not optimal as I've just started to learn plugins and would like to know the best way of doing it?

Comment: @AdRock - probably not the best to use hard coded selectors see here where I added that option with a default that uses classes not the "name" attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/L2t1wgpn/